# Regex challenge: changing formats of negative numbers

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, replace

First of all, I think I have to apologize for not having that much knowledge of regular expressions (yet).
I have searched and searched, but haven't found a solution that matches my specific challenge here.

Now here comes the question:

I am currently experimenting with the development of a parser (meaning to write it myself). I would like to do this while taking regular expressions into account.
Thus far, I have managed to do quite a lot, however, I am running into a small problem. The unary minus sign and the binary minus sign.

What I've learned on University about a decade ago, is that this should be based upon context. However, there is also a simple trick which I use when doing it by hand and that is writing every unary minus in to a different format:

```
-3 = (0 - 3)
```

or

```
5 * -3 = 5 * (0 - 3)
```

A bit more tricky:

```
(5--5)-3 = (5 - (0 - 5)) - 3
```

Now, here is my question, is there a possibility to write a regular expression that translates a **unary minus** expression to a **binary minus** expression by adding *parenthesis and a 0*, like in the examples provided above?

Perhaps there might be another way too, but I am getting a little bit biased here...

Comment:
First I started off with replacing all minus signs with the word MINUS like:

```
expressionBuffer = "-(1-2)-3";
expressionBuffer = Regex.Replace(expressionBuffer, "-", "MINUS");
```

This yields to a new expressionBuffer that looks like:

```
MINUS ( 1 MINUS 2 ) MINUS 3
```

Now, I try to capture the binary '-' operators with applying the following regex:

```
expressionBuffer = Regex.Replace(
                     expressionBuffer, 
                     @"(?<number>((\d+(\.\d+)?)))\s+MINUS", 
                     "${number} -"
                   );
```

And this yields:

```
MINUS ( 1 - 2 ) MINUS 3
```

The first MINUS is clearly a unary operator (but the second is clearly not!) so I am now looking on a way to rewrite that one to the following *(first)* format:

```
( 0 - ( 1 - 2) ) MINUS 3
```

But here I am stuck to treat the first unary minus to a binary minus so that:

```
( 0 - ( 1 - 2) ) - 3
```

Any ideas on how to use a regex for this?

Comment: It seems that minus is unary one if and only if it is 1. the first one, 2. after `(`, `-`, `+`, `*`, `/`; another difficulty is that unary minus can be *nested*: `----1`

Comment: Hi @DmitryBychenko, if I understand your comment correctly then yes, when taking operator precendence into account, absolutely true. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/2QSKDL/2)?

Comment: Try [`Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=^|[-(+*/]\s*)-+\s*(\d*\.?\d+)", "(0 - $1)")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5b-%28%2b*%2f%5d%5cs*%29-%2b%5cs*%28%5cd*%5c.%3f%5cd%2b%29&i=5+*+-3%0d%0a%285--5%29-3%0d%0a%285-------5%29-3&r=%280+-+%241%29)

Comment: @RvdV79: I doubt if it's possible to solve the problem my means of regular expression only in *general case*. To detect if a minus is unary one (operator precendence) is just a part of the work, you have to find out it's argument: `1*-(2+3*(4+5))` -> `1*(0-(2+3*(4+5)))` and this means *pushdown automata*

Comment: Are variables allowed? Like `x --3`?

Comment: Regexes are not used in _parsers_; they are used in _lexers_.

Comment: @AntonGogolev I fully agree, but eventually I will use a lexer (or tokenizer) to build up a structure that can be more easily parsed. Apologies for causing confusion here.

Comment: To speed things up, convert everything to an addition. Do multiple passes from left to right. Alternate these two steps: 1. Convert all `--` to `+`,  2. Convert all `-( a - b)` to `+(-a -- b)`.  Where _a_ and _b_ could be negated as well. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @ndn No variables are required yet, as I am trying to parse simple expressions first. Later on this might be a good thing to do then, so thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @sln That is actually quite a good idea! And it is simple too, now I understand why my wife is always stating that I think too difficult...

Comment: @RvdV79 In the world of _math_ everything is an addition, not a subtraction ..  think positive. When you add everything, you just follow the direction of the numbers sign on the number line. `-3 + -3` means at -3 position go -3 to the left. `-3 + +3` means go to the right 3.

Comment: In reality, everything is an addition and a multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that but you've to call the replacement operation as long as there are changes because the following regex will only replace a single unary operator:

```
private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^|[-(+*/])-(?<value>\d+|\((?:[^\(\)]|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+?(?(open)(?!))\))", RegexOptions.Compiled);

private static string RemoveUnaryOperators(string input)
{
    var result = Regex.Replace(input ?? string.Empty, @"\s+", string.Empty);
    string tmp;
    do
    {
        tmp = result;
        result = _regex.Replace(result, @"(0-${value})");
    }
    while (result != tmp);

   return result;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/KOFncu)

Output:

```
5*-3  ->  5*(0-3)
(5--5)-3  ->  (5-(0-5))-3
(5-------5)-3  ->  (5-(0-(0-(0-(0-(0-(0-5)))))))-3
-(1-2)-3  ->  (0-(1-2))-3
```